# Limit trick using chain rule, is this valid?

Tags: limits, schwartz-space

I want to calculate $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi'(x)}{2x} $$ where $\phi$ is a Schwartz function and $\phi(0) =0$ if that matters. Wondering if this is valid:

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\phi'(x)}{2x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x\phi'(1/x)}{2}$$

Chain rule:

$$\phi'(1/x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}\phi'(x)$$

Gives:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x\phi'(1/x)}{2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} - \frac{\phi'(x)}{2x} = 0 $$

since $\phi'$ is Schwartz. Can I use the chain rule like this?

Comment: Your result is wrong, as $\phi'(0)$ could be different from 0 (making the limit equal to $\pm \infty$)

Comment: Why do you think $\;\phi'\left(1/x\right)=-\frac1{x^2}\phi'(x)\;$ ??

Comment: I guess it's because I'm rusty? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

$\phi'(1/x)$ is the derivative of $\phi$ at $1/x$ (just like $\phi'(4)$ is the derivative of $\phi$ at $4$), that is, you differentiate and *after* this, substitute.

If you define $g(x)=\phi(1/x)$ and you want to differentiate $g$ then you can apply the chain rule, but this is not what you want here.

To solve this problem, you must know $\phi'(0)$. Without further information about $\phi$ you can't find it out. Take for example $\phi(x)=e^{-(x+K)^2}$. These are clearly Schwartz functions for any $K\in\Bbb R$ and $\phi'(0)=-2Ke^{-K^2}$.

Comment: But how do I know $\phi'(x) \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that the limit was as $x\to 0$. Edited.

Comment: Actually, I was missing a puzzle piece. I know that $\phi(0)=0$ as well. I will edit. Does it matter?

Comment: Honestly, not sure. Hvae you any results about Schwartz functions $\phi$ such that $\phi(0)=0$?

Comment: Actually the original problem was to show that $\phi / x$ is Schwartz if $\phi(0)=0$, this was just a step in the attempted solution.